# How to add hyperlink along with text in Textbox

Tags: wpf, hyperlink, textbox, textblock

Here is my code:

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Left">
   <TextBox IsReadOnly="True" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap">    
      Please enter your details for login: questions follow the link 
   </TextBox>
   <Hyperlink NavigateUri="https:" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">
      Reset Password
   </Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

The textbox won't let me set the hyperlink in the text. I need to keep the hyperlink out of textbox, which creates a new line. But I want hyperlink tandem to the text.

My reason for using the TextBox inside the TextBlock is to make the text selectable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest solution utilising single `RichTextBox`:

```
    <RichTextBox IsReadOnly="True" IsDocumentEnabled="True" >
        <FlowDocument>
            <Paragraph>
                Please enter your details for login: questions follow the link
                <Hyperlink NavigateUri="https:" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">Reset Password</Hyperlink>
            </Paragraph>
        </FlowDocument>
    </RichTextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it achieve what you want if you replace your outer `TextBlock` with a `StackPanel`?

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBox VerticalAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap">
        Please enter your details for login: questions follow the link
    </TextBox>
    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Hyperlink NavigateUri="https:" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">
            Reset Password
        </Hyperlink>    
    </TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: It doesn't achieve the requirement because the above stack panel aligns elements horizontally. I had window sizing issue so the text and hyperlink should go into new line.

Comment: @user1118468 then set the StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"